# Visual C# icon issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, icons

I have recently finished a Visual c# project. During the process I tried multiple icons for the form and for the icon you see on your desktop. I found one that I was gonna use for both, but for some reason the icon that you see on your desktop is the old one that I used previously even though I changed it in **Properties -> Application -> Icon and Manifest**

Comment: Did you have performed a `Clean Solution`?

Comment: @xxMUROxx yes, multiple times and it still doesn't work

Comment: Try deleting every `Bin` and `Debug` Folder in your solutions subfolder. And just be sure that the old icon does not exists anymore. Maybe that is only a strange reference issue.

Comment: @xxMUROxx I tried that to, it still does not work. Maybe i should just make a new windowsformsproject and just kinda copy and paste everything?

Answer (score 2):

Windows File Explorer uses an icon cache. You may need to [clear this cache](https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting) to get it to refresh.